# $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is a closed subspace of $L^\infty(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a open set. We denote with $C(\overline{\Omega})$ the vector space of bounded and uniformly continuous function on $\Omega$. We define an application $$\rVert \cdot \lVert\colon C(\overline{\Omega})\to\mathbb{R}_+\quad \lVert f \lVert=\sup_\Omega|f(x)|.$$ We know that $$\left (C(\overline{\Omega}),\lVert\cdot\rVert \right)$$ is a Banach space.

I must prove that $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is a closed subspace of $L^\infty(\Omega)$.

**Solution**

Let $f\in \overline{C(\overline{\Omega})}$, then exists a sequence $\{f_n\}\subseteq C(\overline{\Omega})$ such that $$f_n\to f\quad\text{in}\quad L^\infty(\Omega).$$ Since, in particular, $f_n$ are continuous functions we have that $$f_n\to f\quad\text{in}\quad C(\overline{\Omega}).$$

from here, can I conclude that $f\in C(\overline{\Omega})$? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps explain how you use the assumption "continuous"; more than just "we have that".

Comment: You haven't made very clear the reason why $f$ is continuous... The overall structure and wording of the argument could be improved

Comment: @StratosFair $f_n$ are uniformly continuous and so continuous. It's incorrect? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: the functions $f_n : [0,1]\ni x\mapsto x^n$ are uniformly continuous (as continuous functions on a compact set), but their pointwise limit $f : x\mapsto  1 - \mathbf 1_{[0,1)}(x) $ is not continuous... What's the difference here ?

Comment: Or do I have to show that if $f\in C(\overline{\Omega})$, then exists an bounded and continuous extension $g$ to $\overline{\Omega}$?

Comment: @StratosFairIn your case it is seen that what I want to show is false.

Comment: $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is a strange notation for "the vector space of bounded and uniformly continuous function on $\Omega$". It usually denotes the space of continuous functions on the closure of $\Omega$.

Comment: @AnneBauvalApart from the notation which also seems ambiguous to me, how can I conclude the proof?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the uniform limit of uniformly continuous functions, uniformly continuous itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602258) + [Prove that the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of bounded functions is bounded.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442341)

Comment: Consider $C(\overline{\Omega})$ as a metric subspace of $L^\infty(\Omega)$ with the same metric $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ for both . If you already know that $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is a Banach space then you know that $d$ is a complete metric on $C(\overline{\Omega})$, and since $L^\infty(\Omega)$  shares the same metric, therefore $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is closed in $L^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleetI don't understand what results you are using, could you be more detailed?

Comment: @AnneBauvalWhere do I get uniform convergence? The convergence of $L^\infty$ guarantees uniform convergence up to a set of measure zero, in the end therefore I obtain that f is a bounded function uniformly conitnuam but only almost everywhere. Then how do I conclude?

Comment: The $L^\infty$ norm, for continuous and bounded functions on $\Omega,$ boils down to the $\sup$ norm. And $(f_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy, hence uniformly convergent. Therefore, $f\in C(\bar\Omega),$ by the 2 links above.